# Why is Instagram showing to logins when I've only logged in once Everytime

Tags: security, instagram

Each time I log into Instagram, it shows that there are two sessions under Login Activity even though I've only logged in once and have only one session open in the browser? Is anyone else experiencing this? Been seeing this for the past few months.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have to do with session cookies. I would be storing a new session cookie instead of updating it and passing them both while validating your session. Although, I do not think this should pose a security threat unless these cookies are safe. You can verify that by inspecting the cookies passed by intercepting the requests either from the *Network* tab in the browser Developer Tools or by using a tool like *Burp Suite* or *OWASP ZAP* if you're looking for an open source alternative.

Comment: Thank you for that, I think that's precisely what's happening. Any idea why my browser would generate two cookies? This happens even on a fresh boot where my entire browser history has been cleared. And when I look at the sign in history, I see two sign ins at the same time or sometimes just 1 minute apart. Is this typical behavior?

Comment: I shouldn't be seeing two login attempts on Instagram for each login right? Especially if I'm only logging in on one device?